# Bulk insert into postgres with sequalize raw query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

My requirement is to insert rows in postgres table in bulk using node but with sequalize raw query. I do not want to use ORM for bulk insertion.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1.Firstly you need to create json file which contain json data according to your table columns like :

```
[
    {
        "name": "Leonard",
        "email": "ipsum.Phasellus.vitae@eget.co.uk",
        "password": "JFT82RFL3UV"
    },
    {
        "name": "Anastasia",
        "email": "metus.In@Mauris.edu",
        "password": "CXS22BOP3VU"
    },
    {
        "name": "Marsden",
        "email": "Nunc.pulvinar@iaculis.co.uk",
        "password": "EXX21NDV0PG"
    }
]
```

2.Save it as say **users.json;**

3.Then require it in your main js file :

**const _USERS = require('./users.json');**

4.then you can use it like :-

```
 connection.sync({
        // logging :console.log,
        force: false
    })
   .then(()=>{      
       User.bulkCreate(_USERS); 
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i do not want to use ORM method like bulkCreate. I want to get this functionality with raw insert query.

Comment: gotcha bro refer this docs may be this help you out : [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017